# Как добавить вычисление ответа в код?

Tags: java, математика

Это код парсера математических уравнений, но он не вычисляет ответ.

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

 import java.net.URL;
 import java.text.ParseException;
 import java.util.Collections;
 import java.util.ResourceBundle;
 import java.util.Stack;
 import java.util.regex.Pattern;
 import java.util.StringTokenizer;
 import java.math.BigDecimal;
 import java.util.*;

  import org.apache.commons.math3.*;
  import org.apache.commons.math3.filter.*;
  import org.apache.commons.math3.complex.*;
 import org.apache.commons.math3.complex.ComplexFormat;
  import java.text.Format;

  public class calcConrol implements Initializable {
   @FXML
   private TextField enterField;
   @FXML
   private TextArea textArea;
   private final String[] FUNCTIONS = { "abs", "acos", "arg", "asin", "atan", "conj", "cos", "cosh", "exp", "imag", "log", "neg", "pow", "real", "sin", "sinh", "sqrt", "tan", "tanh" };
  private final String OPERATORS = "+-*/";
   private final String SEPARATOR = ",";
   private final String IMAGINARY = "I";
    private final String VARIABLE = "var";
   private Stack<String> stackOperations = new Stack<String>();
   private Stack<String> stackRPN = new Stack<String>();
   private Stack<String> stackAnswer = new Stack<String>();
 ComplexFormat sad = new ComplexFormat();
  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
 textArea.setEditable(false);
 textArea.setWrapText(true);
 }


public void calculate(ActionEvent event) throws ParseException {
    String getText = enterField.getText();
    try {
        parse(getText);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean isNumber(String token) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(token);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (token.contains(IMAGINARY) || token.equals(VARIABLE)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean isFunction(String token) {
    for (String item : FUNCTIONS) {
        if (item.equals(token)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isSeparator(String token) {
    return token.equals(SEPARATOR);
}

private boolean isOpenBracket(String token) {
    return token.equals("(");
}

private boolean isCloseBracket(String token) {
    return token.equals(")");
}

private boolean isOperator(String token) {
    return OPERATORS.contains(token);
}

private byte getPrecedence(String token) {
    if (token.equals("+") || token.equals("-")) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 2;
}
public void parse(String expression) throws ParseException {
    // cleaning stacks
    stackOperations.clear();
    stackRPN.clear();

    // make some preparations
    expression = expression.replace(" ", "").replace("(-", "(0-")
            .replace(",-", ",0-");
    if (expression.charAt(0) == '-') {
        expression = "0" + expression;
    }
    // splitting input string into tokens
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(expression,
            OPERATORS + SEPARATOR + "()", true);

    // loop for handling each token - shunting-yard algorithm
    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
        if (isSeparator(token)) {
            while (!stackOperations.empty()
                    && !isOpenBracket(stackOperations.lastElement())) {
                stackRPN.push(stackOperations.pop());
            }
        } else if (isOpenBracket(token)) {
            stackOperations.push(token);
        } else if (isCloseBracket(token)) {
            while (!stackOperations.empty()
                    && !isOpenBracket(stackOperations.lastElement())) {
                stackRPN.push(stackOperations.pop());
            }
            stackOperations.pop();
            if (!stackOperations.empty()
                    && isFunction(stackOperations.lastElement())) {
                stackRPN.push(stackOperations.pop());
            }
        } else if (isNumber(token)) {
            if (token.equals(IMAGINARY)) {

                stackRPN.push((sad.format(new Complex(0,1))));
            } else if (token.contains(IMAGINARY)) {
                stackRPN.push(sad.format(sad.parse("0+"
                        + token)));
            } else {
                stackRPN.push(token);
            }
        } else if (isOperator(token)) {
            while (!stackOperations.empty()
                    && isOperator(stackOperations.lastElement())
                    && getPrecedence(token) <= getPrecedence(stackOperations
                    .lastElement())) {
                stackRPN.push(stackOperations.pop());
            }
            stackOperations.push(token);
        } else if (isFunction(token)) {
            stackOperations.push(token);
        }
    }
    while (!stackOperations.empty()) {
        stackRPN.push(stackOperations.pop());
    }
    // reverse stack
    Collections.reverse(stackRPN);

}
}
```

Вопрос: Как можно модифицировать код, что бы он кроме парсинга решал уравнение?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO на русском! К сожалению у нас не приветствуется поднятие своих вопросов удалением их предыдущих копий. Тем паче так скоро. Зачастую ответ можно ждать день-два. К тому же в вашем вопросе явно не хватает описания конкретных ваших затруднений в решении проблемы. Просто так код писать тут мало кому интересно, а вот помочь и направить мы можем. Например, если вы калькулятор пишете, то вам нужно использовать `Польскую нотацию`

Comment: Спасибо, просто в прошлом вопросе я некоректно задал вопрос.

Comment: Вопросы можно править в любой момент - снизу, под метками есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/880135/edit)

Comment: Спасибо!Кстати да, я делаю что-то типа инженерного калькулятора, дело в том, что у меня есть парсер, а что дальше делать - я не знаю（

Comment: Пожалуйста) Вам просто надо найти любой пример кода калькулятора сделанного через Польскую нотацию, разобраться как оно работает и реализовать у себя для всех нужных вам операций с числами.